# html5 camera APi not working, grey box with camera ban sign shows on screen?

Tags: javascript, html, camera

I was trying to access my camera using the HTML5 camera API.
For this I was had been viewing some tutorials/examples :

https://tagawa.github.io/GumWrapper/example.html
https://davidwalsh.name/demo/camera.php

But none seems to be working in my browser.
It asks for camera permission which I allows as always share,

[image]

but even after that my browsers (Both Chrome and Firefox) shows a grey box with camera-ban symbol.

what am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Known issue - What camera are you using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in the HTML, suprisingly - the problem is **in your camera setting**:

### Windows 8 / 10:

1. Open the Windows Start Menu and search "**Lenovo Settings**".
2. If you do not have Lenovo Settings, please install form the [Windows App Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/lenovo-settings/9wzdncrfj12p).
3. Select "**CAMERA**" from the top icons Scroll to the bottom of settings,
   and change **Privacy** Mode from "On" to "**Off**".

[image]

---

### Windows 7:

1. Open the Windows Start Menu and search "Lenovo - Web Conferencing".
2. Once opened, start the camera and close the Lenovo - Web
   Conferencing application.

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding.